# Facebook webhook for pages

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks

I have admin access on one page, I have created facebook app and created and verified webhook on my website.

The problem is that I can't get any data from facebook after my action. I created page and user webhook, then I created php script which will log any time facebook tries to reach that page. Now I can see facebook is calling that page, but I can't get any data from that call. I have printed content of POST but it is giving me value "1".

Also, there is no configuration with which I can set which facebook page I need to track. How can I set it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have printed content of POST but it is giving me value "1".

Facebook does not send the data as a “normal” POST request, it sends JSON directly. Therefor PHP will not populate $_POST – you need to read the raw response body directly, and then decode it.

`file_get_contents('php://input')`, and then `json_decode`.

> Also, there is no configuration with which I can set which facebook page I need to track. How can I set it?

You need to subscribe your app to the page to receive updates, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps

Comment: Thank you, php://input solved the problem. I never saw it before. Now I can fetch data.