# Facebook Messenger Platform Bots : Getting empty request to my webhook

Tags: facebook, bots, webhooks

I have setup a weekhooks for building my first bot for facebook messenger,

all working ok, the only issue i have is that when i message the page i get a call to the webhook but i dont get any information inside of it.

I logged the GET, POST and all is empty

My script is very simple:

```
<?php
file_put_contents('/tmp/test.log',print_r($_POST,true),FILE_APPEND);
```

What i get is :

```
Array
(
)
```

I know it's relative new subject, but did anyone had the same problem ?

Thanks !

Comment: you can check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35999627/facebook-webhook-for-pages/36008361#36008361) that solve my problem too.

Comment: I have the same problem and this solution (on the comment above) not solved it. @maor-bolo Do you any fix? I'm getting empty responses too.

Comment: Thanks ! it worked !

Comment: @Univers3, yes for me it solved the problem